# How to get a variable's byte count?

Tags: php

In PHP, read binary data from MySQL, how to get binary data's length?

For example:

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = 2";
   $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);

   if(!$result)
   {
       echo "Execute query failed!";
       exit;
   }

   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
   // $row["col_varbinary"] is binary data, how to get this data's length?
```

Comment: It's really a string, so treat it as such.

Comment: I have tried strlen(), and it return correct value. But I'm still confused why I can calculate binary data's length with strlen()? It always correct?

Comment: what's wrong with strlen()? why do you think you can't trust it?

Comment: @Spark: Start by telling us why you think it shouldn't work, and then we'll answer your worries. Not the other way around. It sounds like you have, in your mind, imbued "binary data" with magical, transient, non-corporeal properties that don't exist. It's just string data that conventionally consists of characters that aren't in a Western alphabet and which don't tend to form human-language phrases.

Comment: I'm a beginer to PHP. In C/C++, string is terminated by null, and if you call strlen with a binary data, it will crash.

Comment: Also, strlen() return character counts but not byte counts. If string is in unicode, it may incorrect.

Comment: @Spark: No, it won't "crash" at all. In C you should expect "binary data" to contain NULL characters, which may very well cause your "string" to appear shorter than it really is (and this is why you tend to pass around _buffer length_ as well as the buffer pointer itself). In C++ `std::string` can handle arbitrary-length "binary" data strings just fine. And both languages are more low-level than PHP which can also handle this just fine.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961780/php-6-and-strlen

Comment: `strlen() return character counts but not byte counts` - who said you that?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel If you read the link just above your comment you would see that strlen may - and is possibly even likely to change.  It does not seem like a good function to trust in for the future.

Comment: I think PHP5 just don't have a clear way to handle binary data. Even if strlen/mb_strlen can return a correct byte count in some situation, it may cause unexpected bugs in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using PHP's `mb_strlen()` function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

Comment: He asked for the byte length, not the amount of (unicode) characters.

Comment: Using mb_strlen($row["col_varbinary"], '8bit')?

Comment: I love that `Try...`. Means "I have no clue for the question nor answer but just spotted a few familiar words".

Comment: @Spark I think you answered your own question with mb_strlen($row["col_varbinary"], '8bit')

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I appear to have missed the bit where you answered the question

Comment: IT DOES NOT REQUIRE NO ANSWER.

Comment: @Raz It seem you give a good info for this question. Call mb_strlen() with '8bit' is the best way to count bytes I think. I accept your answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
strlen($row["col_varbinary"]);
```

If you are concerned about a new version of PHP which implements multibyte characters in `strlen`, you can try the following:

```
mb_strlen($row["col_varbinary"], 'ISO-8859-1');
```

This would force it into single-byte mode. Not tested for byte counting.